# Simulate packet loss in UDP in python

Tags: python, random, packet-loss

I am supposed to simulate a packet loss rate of 10^-2 in a `Stop-and-wait` protocol, that is 0.01, which means that 1 out of 100 packets transmitted get lost. Suppose I'm sending 1000 packets, how to drop exactly 1 random packet out of the 100 packets sent throughout the transmission ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a rate of 0.01 doesn't mean that exactly 1 out of 100 packets gets dropped.  It means that each packet has a 1% chance of getting lost. Under the assumption that losses are independent of each other, the actual number of lost packets will follow a [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).

For each packet you generate, check if a random Uniform(0,1) is less than or equal to the proportion of losses `p`, in your case 0.01.  If it is, that packet is lost, otherwise it goes through.  This approach scales if you increase or decrease the `N`, the total number of packets.  The expected number of losses will be `N * p`, but if you repeat the experiment multiple times there will be variability.